# Как получить виджет из ячейки QTableView?

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyqt

есть таблица, где в ячейке комбобокс

[image]

как мне получить все значения из этого комбобокса?

так выводит только первое значение
`view.model().index(0, 1).data()`

combobox - это https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqlrelationaldelegate.html

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve]

Comment: проблема, что этот комбобокс это QSqlRelationalDelegate, т.е. сама таблица из бд заполняется. с бд уже не получится ведь пример привести

Comment: в принципе, есть проект на гитлабе с этим, в том числе с дампом бд, которую можно у себя восстановить (постгре), но будет ли кто этим заниматься, непонятно. надеюсь, так кто-то знает

Comment: зависит от того откуда этот комбо берется. без примера кода вам ничем не помочь

Comment: да вон вроде выше написал, это QSqlRelationalDelegate. т.е. возможные внешние ключи подставляются - https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqlrelationaldelegate.html. проблема что я не пойму, как именно к виджету в ячейке доступ получить, никак что ли. в qtablewidget можно было

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Комбо из делегата можно получить следующим образом:

```
delegate = tableView.itemDelegate()
widget = delegate.createEditor(None, QStyleOptionViewItem(), tableView.model().index(0, 1))
if isinstance(widget, QComboBox):
    combo = QComboBox(widget)
    combo.items()
```

Но это неправильно по сути. Сам объект таблицы, делегат и так далее лишь средства отображения данных вашей модели, то есть данные надо брать именно оттуда.

Вот цитата и пример из [документации](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqltablemodel.html):

> QSqlTableModel can also be used to access a database programmatically,
> without binding it to a view.
> перевод: QSqlTableModel также может быть использован для доступа к БД
> программно, без привязки его к отображению.

```
# Создание модели. 
model = QSqlTableModel()

# Установка соответствующей таблицы. В примере "employee", у вас что-то другое
model.setTable("employee")

# SQL-запрос SELECT, то есть получение всех записей из таблицы
# В частности каждый комбо ими и заполняется при отображении
model.select()

# Получение четвертой записи и значения поля "salary" (так в примере)
salary = model.record(4).value("salary").toInt()

# Либо все записи
for i in range(model.rowCount()):
    rec = model.record(i)
    ...
```

То есть в вашем случае, вам надо получить соответствующую модель, затем просто запросить необходимые данные.

Если речь идет не о БД, то поступать нужно тем же образом, то есть получать данные, используя соответствующую модель данных.

Comment: второй способ не пойдет же, так и получит одно значение - текущее (комбобокс уже накинут на view - это возможные внешние ключи). По первому способу почему-то выдает, что это QLineEdit, непонятно почему

Comment: @TemaKam суть в том, что в каждой ячейке (типа комбобокс) таблицы (если вы работаете с БД) находятся данные из одной таблицы БД. Например, список городов это одна таблица БД, список языков другая, в вашем случае в комбо тоже, скорее всего, заполняется из какой-то отдельной таблицы БД. Следовательно, вам нужно обращаться именно к этой таблице через модель. Может быть это список таблиц БД, но тогда надо использовать соответствующие другие средства, но опять же, отображение тут ни при чем

Comment: т.е. если в этот делегат попадают первичные ключи какой-то таблицы (возможные внешние ключи для текущей таблицы), то мне нужно через запрос к той таблице уже вытащить первичные ключи напрямую? по-другому никак?